# How do I properly manage the TypeError in my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I can't figure out how to handle any exceptions for non-int or float inputs on the program below. Could you guys please point me in the right direction?

```
def GradeAverager(): #Creating the function of the grade averager
    #User initiation input
    response = input("\n\nWould you like to average your grades? Press Y for "
                     "Yes or N to exit: ")

    #Defined controlled repsonse variables
    y="Y"
    n="N"

    if response in ["y","Y"]: #If statement based on response (allows for
                              #different variatios of the inputs)

        # User input the # of grades to average
        numOfGrades = float(input("\n\nEnter number of grades to be averaged: "))

        if type(numOfGrades) is not float:
            #Handles non-int exception (NOT WORKING)
            raise TypeError("Only Numbers please!")

        #Defining the variables for the while statement
        x=0
        grades = 0
        rounded_average = 0
        while x < numOfGrades: # While loop to keep asking the user for grades
                               # based on "numOfGrades"
            grades += float(input("\n Enter Grade: ")) # User input is taken
                                                       # and added to grades

            if not type(grades) is not float:
                #Handles non-int exception (NOT WORKING)
                raise TypeError("Only Numbers please!")

            x += 1 # keeps the loop repeating until it is no longer true
        average = grades/numOfGrades # Takes the total of grades and divides it
                                     # by numOfGrades to calculate average
        rounded_average = round(average, 1) #Rounds the total to two one decimal
        print("\n\nYour Grade Average is: " + str(rounded_average))

        #If statements based on result scores
        if average > 70:
            print("\n You are passing but should study harder :|\n\n")
        elif average > 80:
            print("\n Good Job! you're getting there! :)\n\n")
        elif average > 90:
            print("\n Awesome Job! You are Acing this! XD\n\n")
        else:
            print("\n You need to go back and study! :(\n\n")

    elif response in ["n","N"]: #If user answers "no", ends the program
        print("\n\nGood Luck!\n\n")
    else:
        print("\n\nIncorrect Entry\n\n")
        GradeAverager()


print("\n\n*****Welcome to the Grade Averager******") #Prints the title
GradeAverager() #Calls the function
```

Comment: `numOfGrades`  will always be float since you're typecasting to a float so your check doesn't make sense. Unless the input is a string that cannot be converted to a float it will  throw a value error. So it won't even get to your check.

Comment: to expand on previous comment, when you do `float(input(...))` then Python will raise a `ValueError` from `float(...)` if it receives a value that can't be converted, so your `if type(numOfGrades) is not float` check would not be reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have an extra "not" in the line:

```py
if not type(grades) is not float:
```

Change it to:

```py
if not (type(grades) is float):
```

But in general it's better to do it like this:

```py
if isinstance(grades, float):
```

but if you dig deeper, you'll realize that grades will always be of type float, only if the value from the input is correct. You need to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float). Review this and decide how best to check if the input value is a valid representation of a number.

UPD:

And as rightly noted in the comments, almost the same with the `numOfGrades` variable